# Filtering Data from a form to store into a mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-injection

I know there are lots of questions around here and the net with regards to getting data from forms and safely storing them into a database.

I am running PHP version 5+ with `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled.

I have used `strip_slashes` and `mysql_real_escape_string` to store the data, however no one seems to give a definite answer which method(s) is best.

I have a few types of data to collect: a plain text input, an email input and a textarea which includes a WYSIWYG.

The data is collected through a POST method.

I was looking for a safe answer to put my mind at rest.

Answer (score 0):

1) DON'T use magic_quotes_gpc.

2) DON'T use strip_slashes

3) Use prepared statements

Both "plain text", "email" and "textarea" are probably going to be entered as TEXT datatype (or subtype of it like VARCHAR) in the db.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I have looked into prepared statements with mysqli and i seem to reading alot that PDO is a better way to go.. So if i am going to start refreshing with a later method would you recommend PDO or mysqli ??

Comment: If i have a wysiwyg editor on my textarea and still wish to save the data to the database how would you keep the formatting with mysql_real_escape_string ? I have tried just mysql_real_escape_string and it adds \\ to every " etc and ruins the formatting ?

Comment: This is how you escape data so it gets saved  properly. When you pull the data back (with SELECT), it won't have \\. Also try prepared statements.